# Not sure what a .jar file (uploaded onto the plugins folder on minecraft server) should contain

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar, minecraft

I am using **eclipse (Maven)** to create a **Bukkit/Spigot** plugin for Minecraft using the **Java** programming language.

I am using Shockbyte to host the server for the game (a paper server) and am uploading the '.jar' file into the **'plugins'** folder of the server in order for it to record information from the game.

Do I only need to export the **main.java** file that contains the source code to a .jar file (screenshot 1)?

Or do I need to export the **pom.xml** and **plugin.yml** to .jar files too (also seen in screenshot 1)?

If no for the latter question, do I need to add the plugin.yml file directly into my plugins folder on the minecraft server (seen in screenshot 2)?

Would be so grateful for a helping hand!

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plugin.yml` file does need to be included in the JAR file. The `pom.xml` does not need to be (although it would not hurt anything if it were). If you are using Maven, running `mvn clean package` will create a JAR in the `target` folder within your project directory that will contain `plugin.yml` but not `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks! It says build success. Building jar: /Users/macbook/eclipse-workspace/newestplugin/target/newestplugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar - however, I can't see the .jar file inside the target folder. I enter 'mvn clean package' in my terminal on my mac (not the one on eclipse). What might I be doing wrong?